# How to replace empty slots with a custom message using REGEXP_SUBSTR in SQL in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-substr

I have an assignment where I have a table of "suppliers" and each supplier comes with a description. Some descriptions provide an email address while the rest do not. I need to display JUST the email provided, and if there isn't one I need to display "No Email Provided". I was easily able to extract the email addresses, but I can't figure out how to replace all the empty slots with the requested message.

I have tried several, probably very wrong, methods:

**Attempt 1:**

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}') OR 'No email provided' "Supplier emails" FROM suppliers;
```

**Attempt 2:** (Note: I expected this to not work properly but decided to give it a shot anyway out of lack of other ideas)

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}') || 'No email provided' "Supplier emails" FROM suppliers;
```

**Attempt 3:**

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}', 'No email provided') "Supplier emails" FROM suppliers;
```

**Attempt 4:**

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}') "Supplier emails" FROM suppliers;
SELECT REPLACE('-', "No Email Provided") FROM suppliers;
```

I have tried looking this up on Google with variations in the wording, and the textbook I have doesn't clearly explain this specific situation.

This is the table I am using, for context about the results:

```sql
INSERT INTO suppliers
  VALUES ('Second Hand Reads', 
         'wholesaler of used books only, located in Chicago, 634.555-8787');
INSERT INTO suppliers
  VALUES ('Leftovers', 
     'Physical store location, located in Seattle, willing to fill referred sales, sales@leftovers.com');
INSERT INTO suppliers
  VALUES ('Read Again', 
 'Chain of used book store fronts, seeking online sales partner, located in western U.S., 919-555-3333');
INSERT INTO suppliers
  VALUES ('Bind Savers', 'Used book wholsaler, stock includes international titles, 402-555-2323');
INSERT INTO suppliers
  VALUES ('Book Recyclers', 'Used book chain, located in Canada, large volume of sales, 888.555.5204');
INSERT INTO suppliers
  VALUES ('Page Shock', 'Book wholsaler for specialty books and graphic novels, help@pageshock.com');
INSERT INTO suppliers
  VALUES ('RePage', 'Used book vendor, only wholesales, Wash D.C., 555-0122');
COMMIT;
```

The expected output is

```
                           Supplier emails
------------------------------------------------------------------
No email provided
--------------------
sales@leftovers.com
--------------------
No email provided
--------------------
No email provided
--------------------
No email provided
--------------------
help@pageshock.com
--------------------
No email provided
```

But the output was either an error or the one I expected not to work

```
                           Supplier emails
------------------------------------------------------------------
No email provided
-------------------------------------
sales@leftovers.comNo email provided
-------------------------------------
No email provided
-------------------------------------
No email provided
-------------------------------------
No email provided
-------------------------------------
help@pageshock.comNo email provided
-------------------------------------
No email provided
```

Comment: why do your inserts have 3,4,nd 5 column inserts without giving the column names!!!! its not applicable in oracle !!!

Comment: show up your table in tabular form!!!

Comment: @nikhilsugandh: every one of the inserts supplies two values - one appears to be the store name, the other is the description.

Comment: @BobJarvis oh i missed the single quotes thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use either the `NVL` or `COALESCE` functions:

```
SELECT STORE_NAME,
       DESCRIPTION,
       NVL(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}'),
           'No email provided') AS EMAIL
  FROM SUPPLIERS
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3e0324d96c0a236749840a4b13172e20)

`NVL` accepts two arguments. If the first argument is not NULL it returns it; otherwise it returns the second argument.

`COALESCE` is similar to `NVL`, but it accepts as many arguments as you care to supply and returns the first one which is not NULL. If all arguments are NULL `COALESCE` will return NULL.

Best of luck.

Comment: what about emial provided part

Comment: @nikhilsugandh - the query above produces the output specified by OP in his question. I'm a little lost as to what else would be wanted. ???

Comment: I have upvoted  but the user also wants email provided along with the email .A small concatenation will do ||

Comment: Thank you, the NVL function... functioned lol (obviously not a huge deal, but i needed only the emails, i.e. i didn't need the "store_name, description" portion, but that i can do on my own)